# How to convert list into list of list in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have one list and convert split into list of list, please find the below example,

```
List: ['sk','bk', 'ab','4',,'5',6','ku','in']
Expected output:
[
[sk','bk', 'ab','4'],
['5',6','ku','in]
]
```

Note:
The expected output should have 3 lists if the list contains 12 elements

Could you please know how to do it in ansible

Thanks in  advance,
Senthil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are more options.

Given the list declare the variable *step*

```yaml
  l: ['sk', 'bk', 'ab', '4', '5', '6', 'ku', 'in', '12', '34', '56', '78']
  step: 4
```

1. Use Jinja filter [*batch*](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/master/templates/#batch)

```yaml
  l_batch: "{{ l|batch(step) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l_batch:
    - [sk, bk, ab, '4']
    - ['5', '6', ku, in]
    - ['12', '34', '56', '78']
```

---

2. Use [Extended loop variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#extended-loop-variables)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _batch|to_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ range(step, l_lenght|int + step, step)|list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item }}"
        extended: true
      vars:
        l_lenght: "{{ l|length }}"
        split0: "{{ ansible_loop.previtem|default(0) }}"
        split1: "{{ ansible_loop.last|ternary(l_lenght, item) }}"
        _batch: "{{ l[split0|int:split1|int] }}"
```

gives abridged

```yaml
  msg: [sk, bk, ab, '4']
  msg: ['5', '6', ku, in]
  msg: ['12', '34', '56', '78']
```

---

3. Create a custom filter plugin

```py
shell> cat plugins/filter/list_methods.py
def list_split_period(l, p):
    split_list = []
    for i in range(p, len(l) + p, p):
        if i == p:
            split_list.append(l[0:p])
            j = i
        elif i > len(l):
            split_list.append(l[j:])
        else:
            split_list.append(l[j:i])
            j = i
    return split_list


class FilterModule(object):

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'list_split_period': list_split_period,
        }
```

Then, declare the variable

```yaml
  l_split: "{{ l|list_split_period(step) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  l_split:
    - [sk, bk, ab, '4']
    - ['5', '6', ku, in]
    - ['12', '34', '56', '78']
```

---

Notes:

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    l: ['sk', 'bk', 'ab', '4', '5', '6', 'ku', 'in', '12', '34', '56', '78']
    step: 4

    l_batch: "{{ l|batch(step) }}"
    l_split: "{{ l|list_split_period(step) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: l_batch|to_yaml

    - debug:
        var: l_split|to_yaml

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _batch|to_yaml }}"
      loop: "{{ range(step, l_lenght|int + step, step)|list }}"
      loop_control:
        label: "{{ item }}"
        extended: true
      vars:
        l_lenght: "{{ l|length }}"
        split0: "{{ ansible_loop.previtem|default(0) }}"
        split1: "{{ ansible_loop.last|ternary(l_lenght, item) }}"
        _batch: "{{ l[split0|int:split1|int] }}"
```

- Setting `step: 5` gives

```yaml
  l_batch:
    - [sk, bk, ab, '4', '5']
    - ['6', ku, in, '12', '34']
    - ['56', '78']

  l_split:
    - [sk, bk, ab, '4', '5']
    - ['6', ku, in, '12', '34']
    - ['56', '78']

  msg: [sk, bk, ab, '4', '5']
  msg: ['6', ku, in, '12', '34']
  msg: ['56', '78']
```

- For your convenience, the plugin is available among other [List methods at GitHub](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins/blob/master/filter_plugins/list_filters/list_filters.py#L104).

Comment: Hi Vladimir, Thanks for your response,i hope , your logic will work and fullfil requirement , extended loop variables works only ansible version 2.9 but I am using  and ansible version 2.4.2 in my organization ,it is not in my control to upgrade to ansible version.

Comment: You'll need a custom plugin then. This will be more efficient.

Comment: Ya,i will develop module for the same and will make use of it my yaml. It is good stuff and learned extended loop variable  from you. Thanks for your time

Comment: I've updated the answer with the plugin. See the link with code.

Comment: Both are  working like champion and tested in my home machine and i will incorporate with my requirement,Thanks for your valuable time